# Unable to connect remote mysql from nodejs app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Database connection working fine with localhost but not working with remote host.I got the ip from my cpanel that is shared ip. is there anything i am missing?

```
    const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '195.201.179.80',
    user: '****',
    password: '****',
    database: 'enamme_m-tube'
});
db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Connection Established To Mysql Database')
})
```

Note: My Node app is running on localhost.

Error :

> ```
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 195.201.179.80:3306
>     at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should to connect to MYSQL under `root` and send query:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO <db_user>@<remote_ip> IDENTIFIED BY '<db_user_pass>';
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-tube.* TO enamme_enam@195.201.179.80 IDENTIFIED BY '***********'' at line 1

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO enamme_enam@<remote_ip> IDENTIFIED BY '***************';`

Please, note, that `<remote_ip> ` - is client IP. NOT a 195.201.179.80

Answer (score 0):

Did your mysqld binding on public IP address? As default mysqld will bind to the UNIX socket. Try adding this in your /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = <your_public_ip>
```